# Shorten a string inside a SQL Server column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to shorten a string in a column inside a table and I'm not sure how to do that, and I'm sure it's super easy - I think it has something to do with `UPDATE`, but I can't solidify it.

Example "Table" below:

[image]

How can I just shorten the address to just "1462 Dragon Road"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to remove anything after the first comma?

Comment: Most of the time, restricting or removing stuff from a table is not the best of the options. If your need is to show less data, you can always truncate the output in the select statement.

Comment: Yes, everything after "Road" needs to be removed. So I am assuming it is UPDATE?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

use following query

```
UPDATE yourtable 
SET yourcolumn = SUBSTRING(yourcolumn,0, CHARINDEX(',',yourcolumn)) 
-- yourcolumn = LEFT(yourcolumn, CHARINDEX(',', yourcolumn, CHARINDEX(',', yourcolumn)) - 1)
```

Answer (score -2):

I was able to shorten the string inside the table and column successfully using this method below:

```
UPDATE [table]
SET [column] = '[shortened value]'
WHERE [unique identifier for that row] = '[identifier]';
```

Comment: Yes hardcoding the string to assign and the ID of the row in an UPDATE statement will work for this specific case. It is unfortunate that you needed to pose the question in a manner that implied a desire for a generic query that was based on a pattern.